# code-style: Is inline initialization of JS objects ok?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I often find myself using inline initialization (see example below), especially in a switch statement when I don't know which case loop will hit. I find it easier to read than if statements.

But is this good practice or will it incur side-effects or a performance hit?

```
for (var i in array) {
    var o = o ? o : {};  // init object if it doesn't exist
    o[array[i]] = 1;     // add key-values
}
```

Is there a good website to go to get coding style tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another commonly used pattern to do the same, is the use of the [Logical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide:Operators:Logical_Operators) OR `||` operator (a little bit more readable than your ternary IMHO):

```
//...
var obj = o || {};
```

This operator will return its second operand if the first one evaluates to `false`, otherwise it will return the first one.

Is safe to use it when you expect an object, since those *falsy* values are `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, a zero-length string, and of course `false`.

I find it useful to set *default values* on function arguments, when of course any of the *falsy* values are expected as valid by the function:

```
function test (arg1) {
  arg1 = arg1 || "default value";
  //..
}
```

Comment: great tip, I'd recommend watching http://video.yahoo.com/watch/111593 (there are four parts) for other great tips. It's Douglas Crockford's series on JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just declare it outside the loop?

```
var o = {};
for (var i in array) {
  o[array[i]] = 1;
}
```

Otherwise no, I don't see a problem with what you're doing.